# request from python django under docker env to iis on the local machine (outside docker)

Tags: docker, asp.net-web-api, django-rest-framework, docker-compose, iis-express

I try to request an iis webapi that run on my local machine, on the machine i have a docker container that run python django server with postgres. 
I keep getting:

> Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed
>   out'

The system looks like this:

- Client side, react -> run with docker.
- Server side,Django rest frramework with postgress -> docker using
  docker-compose.
- .net webapi that run on local machine iis, This is an old webapi that
  give service for few apps and i have some apis that i need to be open
  for the docker server.

Any idea how to do it?
what am i doing wrong?
Adding the yaml file.

```
 version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
  web:
    build: .
    command: bash -c "python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate && python manage.py runcrons --force && python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    volumes:
      - .:/code
      - /media:/code/media
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
      - '3003:3003'
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      - CLIENT_URL=http://localhost:3000
      - CLIENT_HOST=<host client url>
      - DJANGO_SECRET_KEY=rhkro49pc3lf7@b%zlzncbsl5zbd6r0=vl#4h^)r8j3ilt=6j6
      - DJANGO_DEBUG= TRUE
      - EMAIL_SENDER=<email address>
      # - DJANGO_LOG_LEVEL = INFO
      - DJANGO_DEBUGGER= TRUE
      - CLIENT_URL2= http://10.0.75.1:65298

networks:    
  app-network:
    external: true
```